# Pandas Detect changes of date values in pandas series in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda series as follows:

```
   value0      value1      value2      value3     value4     value5
```

0      2020-10-22  2020-10-22  2020-10-22  2020-10-22  2020-12-02  2020-12-03

Values are of Datetime.date object

I need to find the column names or indices of when date changes.
so the output will be ["value0" , "value4" , "value5"]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `s` is input `Series` first convert to datetimes if necessary, then get difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), compare for not equal `0` and filter index values by this mask:

```
#if input is one row DataFrame
#s = df.T.iloc[:,0]

s = pd.to_datetime(s)

mask = s.diff().dt.days.ne(0)
#alternative
#mask = s.diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(0))

out = mask.index[mask].tolist()
print (out)
['value0', 'value4', 'value5']
```